# Dereferencing null pointer setsize

Tags: java, netbeans, syntax-error

So I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error (Dereferencing null pointer).

I have to initialize newframe because otherwise I get a not initialized error and NetBeans suggests that I initialize it. However after doing so, I keep getting this error. Below is a snippet of code that is giving me the problem.

```
public class InventoryGUI2 {

private static ArrayList<inventoryItem> inventory = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    makeWindow();
}

public static void makeWindow() {

    final JTextArea outputText;
    JFrame newFrame = null;

    newFrame.setSize(400, 600);
    newFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension dim = tk.getScreenSize(); //get screen size from host OS
    int xPos = (dim.width / 2) - (newFrame.getWidth() / 2); //Center the Screen horizontally
    int yPos = (dim.height / 2) - (newFrame.getHeight() / 2); //center the screen vertically

    newFrame.setLocation(xPos, yPos);
    newFrame.setResizable(false);
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: You write `JFrame newFrame = null;`
which implies that newFrame is null. Then afterwards, you perform a method call on a null pointing variable:
`newFrame.setSize(400, 600);`

Comment: What is weird is that this seems to compile fine, but it just won't run at all. I keep getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at inventorygui2.InventoryGUI2.makeWindow(InventoryGUI2.java:26)
 at inventorygui2.InventoryGUI2.main(InventoryGUI2.java:18) where line 26 is the newFrame.setSize and 18 is the makeWindow();

Comment: I get that I am initializing it and then telling it to set the size to something other than null, but how else can I do such a thing? Should I set the size at declaration?

Comment: It will compile fine. since you are assigning newFrame to null. If you left newFrame unassigned, then the compiler would complain that it might be null. Try it.
And from the stack trace, it suggest that the error is at makeWindow()

Comment: assign newFrame to a new object of JFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should like this..

```
JFrame newFrame = new JFrame();
```

Comment: This worked to allow the program to run - Thank you. I hadn't thought to set it to a new JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you are trying to set values in null in following initialize newFrame before setting values

```
JFrame newFrame = null;

    newFrame.setSize(400, 600);
```

add this line as well

```
JFrame newFrame = new JFrame();
```